# Prove that the binomial coefficient $\binom{N}{5}$ is even if and only if N is congruent to 1(mod 8) or 3(mod 8) or 0 (mod 2)

Tags: modular-arithmetic, binomial-coefficients

Prove that the binomial coefficient $\binom{N}{5}$ is even if and only if N is congruent to 1(mod 8) or 3(mod 8) or 0 (mod 2)

Proving that if n is congruent to 1(8) or 3 (8) or 0(2) then $\binom{N}{5}$ is even was easy, but I can't think of a way to prove the implication backwards

Comment: you can't use dollar signs and thinks like _^ they are usually on another keyboard on android tablets for example.

Comment: To my knowledge, the binomial coefficients are never referred to as "a combinatory."  That doesn't even sound like a word.  I've edited accordingly.  As for difficulties typing on a phone, its not really worth including in the question itself.  Consider putting that as a comment instead.

Comment: As for the reverse implication, all that remains is to show that if $n$ is congruent to $5$ or $7$ mod8 that $\binom{N}{5}$ is odd instead of even.

Comment: http://www.yourdictionary.com/combinatory  shows it is a word. though I don't think it was used correctly, as used in the OP.

Comment: In general, $\binom{n}{k}$ is odd if and only if the places in the binary representation of $k$ containing a 1 are a subset of the places in the binary representation of $n$ containing a 1.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Assuming you have finished proving the forward direction, all that remains is to prove the reverse which can be done by contrapositive.  Try to prove then that when $N$ is $5$ or $7$ mod8 that the binomial coefficient is odd.

$\binom{N}{5}=\frac{N!}{5!(N-5)!}=\frac{N(N-1)(N-2)(N-3)(N-4)}{5!}$

How many terms in the numerator are multiples of $2$ but not multiples of $4$?

How many terms in the numerator are multiple of $4$ but not multiples of $8$?

How many terms in the numerator are multiples of powers of $2$ which are $8$ or higher?

What then is the largest power of two which divides the numerator?

How about the denominator?

Answer (score 0):

If $n$ is even ($n\equiv 0 \mod 2$).  Then $n, n-2, n-4$ are even and at least one of $n,n -4$ is divisible by $4$ so $(n-4)*(n-3)*(n-2)*(n-1)*n$ is divisible by $16$ (and maybe by a higher power of $2$).  $5! = 120$ is divisible by $8$ but not $16$.  So ${N\choose 5} = \frac {(n-4)*(n-3)*(n-2)*(n-1)*n}{5!}$ is divisible by $2$ (and maybe a higher power of $2).

If $n$ is not even then $n \equiv 1,3,5,7 \mod 8$.  If $n \equiv 1 \mod 8$ then $n-1$ is divisible by $8$ and $n-3$ is divisible by $2$.  If $n \equiv 3 \mod 8$ then $n-3$ is divisible by $8$ and $n-1$ is divisible $2$.  Either way, $(n-4)*(n-3)*(n-2)*(n-1)$ is divisible by $16$ (by no higher power of $2$) and ${N\choose 5} = \frac {(n-4)*(n-3)*(n-2)*(n-1)*n}{5!}$ is divisible by $2$ (but no higher power of $2$).

If $n\equiv 5 \mod 8$ then $n-5$ is divisible by $8$.  And $n-3$ is divisible by $2$ but not $4$ and $n-1$ is divisible by $4$ but not $8$ and $(n-4)*(n-3)*(n-2)*(n-1)$ is divisible by $8$ but not $16$.  Likewise if $n-7$ is divisible by $8$; $n-3$ is divisible by $4$ and $n-1$ is divisible by $2$ and $(n-4)*(n-3)*(n-2)*(n-1)$ is divisible by $8$ but not $16$. So $5! = 120$ is also divisible by $8$ but not $16$ so ${N\choose 5} = \frac {(n-4)*(n-3)*(n-2)*(n-1)*n}{5!}$ does not have $2$ as a factor and must be odd.

Answer (score 0):

We provide a method for determining when a binomial coefficient is a multiple of a prime $p$.

We first prove the following:

Lemma: Let $p$ be a prime and let $m,n$ be natural numbers. Let $n = lp+t$ and $m = kp+s$, where $0 \leq t < p$ and $0 \leq s < p$. Then
\begin{align*}
\binom{n}{m} = \binom{l}{k}\binom{t}{s}\mod p 
\end{align*}
Proof: Observe first that for $0 < r < p$, $\binom{p}{r}$ is divisible by $p$. Hence in
$$ (1+X)^p - (1+X^p) = \binom{p}{1}X + \binom{p}{2}X^2+\cdots + \binom{p}{p-1}X^{p-1} $$
all the coefficients are divisible by $p$.

Now, consider
\begin{align*}
 P(X) &= (1+X)^{lp+t} - (1+X)^t (1+X^p)^{l} \\
 &= (1+X)^t\left\{(1+X)^{lp} - (1+X^p)^l \right\} \\
 &= (1+X)^t \left\{(1+X)^p - (1+X^p)\right\}\left\{(1+X)^{p(l-1)} + \cdots + (1+X^p)^{l-1}\right\}
\end{align*}
As observed before, $P(X)$ is a multiple of $p$.

Consider the coefficient of $X^{kp+s}$ in $P(X)$. This equals
\begin{align*}
 \binom{lp+t}{kp+s} - \binom{t}{s}\binom{l}{k}
\end{align*}
and hence all the coefficients are multiples of $p$. Note that this holds even when $k = 0$ or $l=0$. This completes the proof of the lemma.

Applying the Lemma repeatedly,  it follows that if
\begin{align*}
 n &= t_1+t_2p+t_3p^2+\cdots + t_rp^{r-1} \\
 m &= s_1+s_2p+s_3p^2+\cdots + s_rp^{r-1}
\end{align*}
then
\begin{equation*}
\binom{n}{m} = \binom{t_1}{s_1}\binom{t_2}{s_2}\cdots\binom{t_{r-1}}{s_{r-1}} \mod p
\end{equation*}

We use the lemma to find when $\binom{N}{5}$ is even. Writing $N$ and 5 in binary notation, we get
\begin{align*}
N &= a_0 + 2a_1 + 2^2 a_2 + 2^3 a_3 + \cdots \\
5 &= 1 + 2 \times 0 + 2^2 \times 1
\end{align*}
Thus $\binom{N}{5}$ is even if and only if either $a_0 = 0$ or $a_2 = 0$

If $a_0 = 0$, then $N$ is $0 \mod 2$. If $a_0 \neq 0$, then $a_2 = 0$  gives $N = 1 $ or $3 \mod 8$